# Vote count is no longer displayed when I hover on it

Tags: bug, tags, profile-page, tooltips

For some time now when I open the tags view and hover the votes for a given tag I do not see detailed information.

[image]

Now for `algorithm` and `java` this is not a problem, but for `c++` I am no longer able to see any statistics. I remember a few weeks ago when I hovered the `1k` next to `c++` I got something of the sort of `1086 votes from 580 answers`.

Is this a bug or was this feature deliberately removed. If it was removed intentionally then: why?

I am using chrome(Version 32.0.1700.107) on 64 bit ubuntu 12.04.

EDIT: thanks to Shadow Wizard this issue is related to a bug in chrome and tooltips are not shown if sound is playing. Once I stop youtube, I see tooltips as expected.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this; the `title` attribute is there and I see the tooltip (Chrome 32 on Mac OS X).

Comment: The HTML for your C++ score count is: `<div class="answer-votes" title="Asked 15 non-wiki questions with a total score of 33. Gave 578 non-wiki answers with a total score of 1106." onclick="window.location.href='/search?q=user:812912+[c%2b%2b]'">1k</div>`

Comment: Do you have any extensions that might place an invisible HTML element over your profile page that might block the mouse-over here?

Comment: Can you see other tooltips? When you view the HTML source, do you see the title attributes as posted by @Martijn in the above comment?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't think so, at least not one that I can see.

Comment: @MartijnPieters When I open the source code I see something similar to what you post. At least now I can see my votes.

Comment: Hovering over `c++` opens up the wiki summary for `c++` btw.

Comment: @MartijnPieters actually on second thought I have flashblock which is disabled for stackoverflow

Comment: @izomorphius: Hovering over the tag opens the tag popup like everywhere else in the site. Hovering over the *score* before it shows the score breakdown.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I know. I only posted the previous to prove I see some popups. I have also verified the score breakdown is not visible in incognito(where no extensions work I think) and also I have checked I see the score breakdown on windows

Comment: @izomorphius: Extensions can be enabled in Ingonito mode too, per extension.

Comment: @izomorphius did you try in another browser?  This is certainly happening client side.

Comment: @NickCraver firefox on linux shows the breakdown, so I guess the problem is chrome related

Comment: @izomorphius you have to edit your extensions at `chrome://extensions`, there's a check that still allows each to work in incognito mode.

Comment: @NickCraver all are not allowed in incongnito.

Comment: Lix [found the bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223138/how-to-know-the-time-of-chat-message/223139?noredirect=1#comment726734_223139): https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=333002 @Nick FYI as well.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I confirm this is the problem. I have verified that once I stop the sound from youtube I see the tooltip. Thank you!

Comment: @ShadowWizard please post this as an answer so that I can accept it. You are the one to drill this one and I have no idea how you did it but you deserve at least a dozen accepts for the effort

Comment: Not me, Lix is the one who found that Chrome bug so all fame should be his. ;-)

Comment: FYI - the chrome bug seems to have been fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### STOP LISTENING TO MUSIC!

No... really... I suspect that your issue could be related to [this fantastically weird bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=333002). (that has since been fixed).

Closing the tab that was generating the audio and waiting a few seconds solved the tooltip issue for me while trying to answer [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223138/how-to-know-the-time-of-chat-message).

It seems like every tooltip you encounter will be affected by this.