# How to know the time of chat message?

Tags: discussion, chat

How to know the time of message in chat window. The following screenshot displays two message of chat window. You can see the first message does not shows the time and second is displaying. How can I see first message time?

[image]

Comment: I think if we get continuous chat in specific time then it will display timings on chat from which the chat is initialized. And if after that if we have chatted after one hour then it will display the timing in that chat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clicking on the little arrow on the top left side of a message will bring up a little dropdown that provides more actions and the time when the message was posted:

[image]

Hovering over the timestamp in the tooltip should give you an exact timestamp.

```
<span title="9:32">posted 2h ago</span>
```

---

The tooltip is not working for me [(because reasons)](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=333002), so here is a much more convoluted way to get at the info... it involves quite a few clicks. Here's how it's done:

1. Click on the permalink to a chat message.
2. When in the transcript view of the chat, click the top left arrow (as before).
3. Click on the history link.

[image]

This will bring up a page like this:

[image]

As you can see, it contains a more exact timestamp and also the timestamps of any edits made to the message.

Comment: Hovering the time will show the exact absolute time.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - I can see the `title` attribute on the HTML element, but for some reason it's not working for me...

Comment: @ShadowWizard You're right, Exact time has given in the tooltip of **posted [T]h ago**.

Comment: Weird, Lix... I blame some user script or browser extension you got. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard - place your blame elsewhere! https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=333002. What a weird weird weird bug...

Comment: Wow, that's a nasty bug! So don't hear music! :D

Comment: @sha but but but but podcast!!

Comment: podcast is so 2012!

Comment: @Lix if you want to get some points and fame, you can answer [this other bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222749/vote-count-is-no-longer-displayed-when-i-hover-on-it?noredirect=1#comment726743_222749) and explain it's caused by that weird Chrome bug. OP confirmed that's the problem and I don't want to steal your Karma! :P

Comment: @ShadowWizard - cool :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think if we get continuous chat in specific time then it will display timings on chat from which the chat is initialized. And if after that if we have chatted after one hour then it will display the timing in that chat.

You can look at this chat. In which you get the clear idea. [image]

Just look at the timings displayed in Image. its showing `8.36` after that message was at `8.53` and then `9.11`.

In `10:56` there are 4 messages but its showing the timings only for one time because it was posted at the duration of 10 mins.

Comment: funny to see you and the OP sanitize their screenprints while the chat transscript is publicly available to everybody...

Comment: @rene - buddy its just an example...and btw what's so funny in that if we do hide that then??